# Is there a way to apply GMSMapStyle in GMSMapView right away?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm implementing the night style in my app with google map view. I've been following "Quick Map Styling - Night Mode" guide, and I've noticed that the style applies with the small delay, but it's enough to flash user. Is there a way to apply style right away, so users won't be flashed with custom background color of google map?
 Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *styleUrl = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"GoogleMapNightStyle" withExtension:@"json"];
    NSError *error;
    style = [GMSMapStyle styleWithContentsOfFileURL:styleUrl error:&error];
    _mapView.mapStyle = style;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I'm presenting UIView with the same color of my custom style with size of mapview above the mapview for a short amount of time (enough to cover "flash").